# Is AddWithValue only dangerous for strings?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, ado.net, sqlparameter

Several answers give you warnings about `AddWithValue`. These [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518012142/http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/how-data-access-code-affects-database-performance) are commonly given. The impression that I get is that it's dangerous because `AddWithValue` has to guess the SQL type of your C# data, leading to the usage of bad query plans. However, in my use case, nearly all of my parameters are ints in C# that are passed to parametrised stored procedures in SQL. I can't imagine many wrong SQL guesses for what type a C# int could be.

Does the above mean that I'm free of the performance risks of using `AddWithValue`? If so, was I already free because `AddWithValue` is only dangerous with C# stings? Or was I already free because using stored procedures rather than parametrised queries already saves the day?

Comment: Perhaps "dangerous" is a bit of an exaggeration. Probably "inefficient" is better (if you use it correctly). The real problem with that method, in my opinion, is the fact that it let you pass anything in the value. So you could pass a string like "28/12/1980" when the database expects a date. Now with "AddWithValue" you leave the job of translating that value to a date to its algorithm and the results could be impredictable.

Comment: @Steve I'm definitely paranoid about passing dates with `AddWithValue` and will always use just `Add` for that.

Comment: That's good but still I prefer to avoid it in any case. In my career, in more than one occasion, I have seen fellow programmers look at code written from others and copy/paste it without critical thinking. Leaving that pitfall around in my code is something that make me uncomfortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.Net always has to guess your parameter type, but yes some types always have a fixed mapping.

The following parameter types can be problematic

- `(n)(var)char`
- `(var)binary`
- `decimal`
- `float`
- `real`
- `(small)money`
- `(small)(date)(time)(2/offset)`

These ones just mentioned are problematic not just because of the parameter type, but also because of the length/precision/scale.

The other types, such as `int`, may not match the type you pass in, and you are advised to always use the correct type just in case. Yes, it's true that `int` is always mapped to `int`, but many of the others do not. It's probably best to get into the habit of always specifying it.

> Does the above mean that I'm free of the performance risks of using AddWithValue?

Yes, in that specific case, but I still wouldn't do it.

> If so, was I already free because AddWithValue is only dangerous with C# strings?

No, there are other problematic data types also, as mentioned.

> Or was I already free because using stored procedures rather than parametrised queries already saves the day?

Stored procedures convert what you send *back* to the correct data type automatically, with a slight overhead. In the case of certain data types there may be a loss of data (precision or certain characters). Eg if you pass an `nvarchar` as a `varchar` then extended character sets may be lost completely, and procedures do not help here

Comment: Excellent. I've accepted the answer. If you've got any documentations or clear tests to back what you've said up, then that's even better, but this will do.

Comment: You can easily test it yourself. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` and see what you get

Comment: It's easy to see what ADO.NET sends to the server. It's less easy to see what the server actually gives the stored procedure. My best attempt was to make a C# `string` out of something that can't be a `VARCHAR`, notice that that `AddWithValue` made an `NVARCHAR` out of it, and then send that to a stored procedure that expects a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I don't understand you. If the procedure parameter is declared as `varchar` how could it not be an `varchar`? Yes that's one obvious way to tell. You can also see that pretty quickly if you just do `SELECT @param1` and check the schema of the data you receive.

Comment: I think we both agree and my paranoia about `AddWithValue` has merely got the better of me.

Comment: I still think you should declare them properly, there is still the conversion overhead and possible conversion losses. What does it cost you, a few more letters to type?