# Code working to input data into access database but when retrieving the data "Column "XYZ" does not belong to table ."

Tags: .net, oledb, sqlclient

I am a bit new to coding so please excuse my lack of knowledge. Using C#, .NET 8.0 with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.OleDb NuGet packages.

I have an application that I have written that imports information from a PDF form and exports the data to an Access database. I recently added a feature to the application that uses tables in the Access database to populate 3 dropdown boxes in the form. This code works perfectly fine to populate the drop box options and the rest of the code works fine to input information into the database.

The error "An error occurred: Column 'Special' does not belong to table ." comes up when I try to pull information from the database into my form. one of three of these drop boxes (Status) works without issue but the other two (Special and Priority) provide this error.

I have validated there are no spelling or capitalization errors and my code references and imports data to these columns without issue.

Below is a simplified version of my method. I removed most of the repetitive code. The three code sections pertaining to my issue are labeled as // Revised inline selection for X ComboBox

```
    private void btnExistingRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the current RequestNum value
        string tempRequestNum = RequestNum.Text;

        // Clear the form
        ClearForm();

        // Restore the RequestNum value
        RequestNum.Text = tempRequestNum;

        using (OleDbConnection connection = dbHelper.GetConnection())
        {
            // Fetch data from ToolingRequests table
            string queryToolingRequests = "SELECT * FROM ToolingRequests WHERE RequestNum = ?";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryToolingRequests, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", RequestNum.Text);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read()) // if data found
                        {
                            // Load Text fields
                            RequestNum.Text = reader["RequestNum"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["RequestNum"].ToString();

                            // Prevent StatusDate from updating when Status is set
                            shouldUpdateStatusDate = false;

                            // Revised inline selection for Status ComboBox
                            string statusValue = reader["Status"]?.ToString();
                            var statusItem = Status.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row["Status"].ToString() == statusValue);
                            if (statusItem != null)
                                Status.SelectedItem = statusItem;
                            else
                                Status.SelectedIndex = -1;

                            // Revised inline selection for Special ComboBox
                            string specialValue = reader["Special"]?.ToString();
                            var specialItem = Special.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row["Special"].ToString() == specialValue);
                            if (specialItem != null)
                                Special.SelectedItem = specialItem;
                            else
                                Special.SelectedIndex = -1;

                            // Revised inline selection for Priority ComboBox
                            string priorityValue = reader["Priority"]?.ToString();
                            var priorityItem = Priority.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row["Priority"].ToString() == priorityValue);
                            if (priorityItem != null)
                                Priority.SelectedItem = priorityItem;
                            else
                                Priority.SelectedIndex = -1;

                            // Load ComboBox values
                            UOM.SelectedItem = reader["UOM"] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader["UOM"].ToString();

                            // Re-enable updating StatusDate
                            shouldUpdateStatusDate = true;

                            // Load DateTimePicker values
                            SetDateTimePickerValue(MaintCalDate, reader["MaintCalDate"]);

                            // Load CheckBox values
                            OpShtCheck.Checked = reader["OpShtCheck"] != DBNull.Value && reader["OpShtCheck"].ToString().Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No data found for the specified Request Number.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // After reading data and populating fields
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ToolNum.Text))
                    {
                        // Check if ToolNum is populated
                        btnExistingTool_Click(null, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried pulling this information with the same lines I use for pulling the other comboboxes

UOM.SelectedItem = reader["UOM"] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader["UOM"].ToString();

but this didn't pull any information for the fields. So I revised the code to the new snippet but it only works for the Status field.

Edit:
Updated code section per Dour High Arch recommendation still not working.

```
            // Fetch data from ToolingRequests table
            string queryToolingRequests = "SELECT RequestNum, WO, PO, ToolNum, ProdPart, Type, RefTool, Qty, UOM, ProdCustomer, Other, Reason, ReqDate, Priority, Department, Requestor, Status, SupPE, supext, reqext, StatusDate, ToolNotes, APCheck, AP, APDate, RefDocCheck, RefDoc, RefDocDate, MaintCalCheck, MaintCalSch, MaintCalDate, CalProCheck, CalPro, CalProDate, OtherCheck, OtherCrit, OtherDate, SF343Check, SF343, SF343Date, ERCheck, ERNum, ERDate, OtherValCheck, OtherVal, OtherValDate, DOECheck, DOERej, DOEDate, DOQCheck, DOQRej, DOQDate, Reject, CompDate, ME, MEDate, OpSht, OpShtDate, OpShtCheck, PEApv, PEDate, QEApv, QEDate, Special FROM ToolingRequests WHERE RequestNum = ?";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryToolingRequests, connection))
            {
                // Use .Add method with the correct data type
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = RequestNum.Text;
```

[ToolingRequests Access table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBRvR.png)

I fiend of mine was able to diagnose the problem and it revolved around the item array. When the form was attempting to populate the combobox the item array needed to be set to [0] and not the search value. This allowed the code to iterate through the array of values provided by the Access database.

```
        // Revised inline selection for Status ComboBox
        string statusValue = reader["Status"]?.ToString();
        var statusItem = Status.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString() == statusValue);
        if (statusItem != null)
        {
            Status.SelectedItem = statusItem;
        }
        else
        {
            Status.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Comment: 1. [Do not use `SELECT *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/), specify each column name you want. 2. [Do not use `AddWithValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242983/), use `.Add` with the correct data type. 3. Edit your post to include the schema of your `ToolingRequests` table.

Comment: I updated the code as recommended and I'm still not pulling the data from these combo boxes. I also verified that the source tables to populate the combo boxes did not share any similar names. I tried this with the "// Revised inline selection for Status ComboBox" and "// Load ComboBox values" codes and I'm still unable to get the data to pull into the form. Updated code section provided in post edit.

Comment: Thanks. I do not use OleDB, but my guess is that `Special` and `Priority` are reserved words. I don't know the OleDB syntax, but try escaping them in your query like `SELECT [Special], [Priority], Status, ...` or `SELECT "Special", "Priority", Status, ...`.

Comment: I tried this as well. [*] was the appropriate format for escaping them but the issue still persists.

Comment: You should [run your code in the debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and look at the values of `cmd` and `reader` for anything unexpected. When you ask about an exception you need to [post the full exception](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) from `ex`, not just `ex.Message`.

Comment: I ran through debugging and when the code reaches the line to pull the Status value from the database it correctly pulls the value. 
Code line: var statusItem = Status.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Row["Status"].ToString() == statusValue);

Value = "Quoting"
object.ToString returned = "Quoting"
statusItem = null
statusValue = "Quoting"

Because statusItem returns a null value the code jumps to the catch error line and stops the rest of the code from running.

Comment: Post additional information to your question, not in a comment. `FirstOrDefault` is allowed to return null so you have to handle that. I notice some times you do `reader["foo"]?.ToString()` and some times you do `reader["foo"] == DBNull.Value ? null`. Why? `null` and `DBNull.Value` are different values. Try running you query from your data source, not your application, and show us what it is returning. Note that if you have many columns with many nulls [you've created your database wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157778/drowning-in-a-sea-of-nulls).

Comment: I was fortunate enough to be able to get a computer science friend of mine to review the code and after about 2 hours of debugging we found the issue. The solution has been added to the end of the post.

Comment: If you found the solution you should put it in the Your Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer.